# How to display C program errors in asp.net web page using c#

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, c, compiler-construction

I am creating online compilers application. I have successfully created with C#.net and VB.net. But when I am trying with C and C++ I don't know how to display the errors in asp.net webpage.

The following only displays the error but not the location of the error in the code

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = Session[batchPath].ToString();
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.Start();
```

Is it right or I should do any modification? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You get the results from your Process using the [`StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx) as

```
string cResults = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
// and then wait to exit.
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get the error list of a C program. I have used the following code for C# and VB.net.  CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, txtProgram.Text);

        if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            txtCompiler.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)

Comment: @Balaji The c compiler is return the error list on the console as you run it on your example, there you read the errors as I type it. Do you ever have direct run the c compiler to see whats return ? Then you need to parse this errors... I do not know what you really try to do. You do not even have type what program you run. When you compile your visual studio programs, do you have note the Output window ?

Comment: I understand what you are telling but i want to know the exact line of the program where the error occurs. Can u pls provide me the code for that.

Comment: @Balaji We probably not talk the same language here, because I do not understand what more you look for ? For the code you provide, and if you run the c compiler that way, on the `cResults` you have the return of the compiler. There you parse the errors and you have your lines. Also I do not even know what program you run, what compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

- run the compiler
- redirect its error output to a text file
- parse the text file to find the text of the errors, line and column no
- convert that into your own formatted error messages
- convert that into something you can display in HTML.

The only hard part is parsing the error file, but you're not the first. Everyone does it, including all the IDEs. Maybe you can get some code out of Eclipse or Netbeans or somewhere.